# C++ identify data structure from adress

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, stl, polymorphism

I would like to know if there is a way in C++ to know in what data structure an address is. For example, I have a base class (A) that has two inherited class (B and C). In a fourth class (D), I have two vectors of the STL, one containing pointers of B, the second containing pointers of C.

In D, I am implementing a method that is withdrawing an object A. In that method, I am using another implemented function of D that is searching in the vectors if the object A is there and return a pointer to this object.

Is there a way after that to manipulate the appropriate vector of where the object A to directly delete it from the vector (knowing in what vector it is and its position in the vector) ?

```
A* D::findA(string word)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vectorOfB_.size(); i++) {
        if ( vectorOfB_[i]->getWord() == word)
            return vectorOfB_[i];
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vectorOfC_.size(); i++) {
        if (vectorOfC_[i]->getWord() == word)
            return vectorOfC_[i];
}

bool D::withdrawA(string word)
{
    A* obj = findA(word);
    if (obj != nullptr) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

At this point, I know that the method found the object A, I know its address, but I don't know in what vector it is. I would like to use the erased() method of the STL vector class to withdraw it from the vector, but without doing loops again to go check in the vectors.

Comment: Please provide an example and maybe some use case of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why do you have an inheritance hierarchy if the base class is not a common enough denominator?

Comment: You mean just a vector of A ? The exercise that I am working needs to have two different vectors of the inherited classes so it makes it longer to code and is teaching us after that in what way the polymorphism is useful.

Comment: Sorry to say, but the exercise seems misguided. You either care about the concrete type of the object (in which case you get it by the concrete type `B` or `C`) or you don't, and than you operate via an `A` pointer or reference.

Comment: How can I operate via the A pointer ?

Comment: I would like to call the erased() method of the appropriate vector. Is their a way to use the A pointer to call the erased() method of the vector?

Comment: Refactor. Have separate lower level private functions to look in each specific vector. Than have both `findA` and `withdrawA` rely on those. To save yourself the work you may write a single template function to do it.

Comment: The functions I have to implement and the attributes I have to use for each classes are given by the exercise and can not be changed.

Comment: Did it say you can't **add** *private* functions? And tag me if you reply directly to me. I cannot see your responses in my feed.

Comment: @StoryTeller I can not add any other functions or change the prototype of any functions. Can not change the classes too.

Comment: The thing is, that you could do what you asked, if your vectors contained objects instead of pointers. Since the vectors memory is contiguous.

Comment: Ok thank you. It is confirmed that you can not, in C++, know the vector by an element of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, there is no way to directly know the data structure by an address.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use dynamic_cast to determine if the pointer of A is of type B or C.

```
bool D::withdrawA(string word)
{
    A* obj = findA(word);
    if (obj != nullptr) {
        if(dynamic_cast<B*>(obj) != nullptr) {
           // do something here for the B vector
        }
        else if(dynamic_cast<C*>(obj) != nullptr)
        {
           // do something here for the C vector
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That will make me have to go again with a loop in the vector. I want to know if there is a way to directly call the erased() method of the appropriate vector.

Comment: Can't you alter the findA function so it takes a second parameter passed by reference(of type int) that would suggest the position(i)? If you can then you won't need a second loop.

Comment: Can not even change the prototypes of the functions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are querying a member of the class (`word`) in order to identify the object, I don't think you need some maginc machanism to achive what you want.

You can use the STL algorithms for that, for instance having the classes:

```
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


using namespace std;


class A {
public:
    A(string word = "") :m_word(word){}
    virtual inline string getWord() { return m_word; }
protected:
    string m_word;
};

class B : public A { 
public: 
    B(string word = "") : A(word) {} 
};  

class C : public A { 
public:
    C(string word = "") : A(word) {} 
};


typedef shared_ptr<A> a_ptr;      
typedef vector<a_ptr> a_vector;
```

You can write a function:

```
a_ptr find_A(a_vector v, string word, bool erase = false){

    // Find the element.
    auto it = find_if(v.cbegin(), v.cend(),
        [word](const a_ptr &elem) {
            return elem->getWord() == word;
        }
    );

    // If you want to erase and it was found.
    // The code below can be implemented in a more elegant way, but
    // for that your classes will require you overload < operator and == operator.
    if (erase && it != v.end()) {
        v.erase(remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), 
            [word](a_ptr elem){
                return elem->getWord() == word;
            }
        ), v.end());
    }

    return *it
}
```

Now you an use that function with both vectors.

---

### A more specific example.

You can use STL algorithms in order to erase from your vectors too:

Suppose you have found some `A*`

```
A* a_ptr =  findA(word);
```

Then you can use STL erase, remove_if idiom:

```
vectorOfB_.erase(remove_if(vectorOfB_.begin(), vectorOfB_.end(), 
    [a_ptr](A* elem){
        return elem->getWord() == a_ptr->getWord();
    }
), vectorOfB_.end());

vectorOfC_.erase(remove_if(vectorOfC_.begin(), vectorOfC_.end(), 
    [a_ptr](A* elem){
        return elem->getWord() == a_ptr->getWord();
    }
), vectorOfC_.end());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is specific in my situation that I can not change the prototypes of functions or the classes. It seems like there is not a shortcut to achieve what I need in that case.

Comment: My example is only a guide on how you can achive what you want. I´ll put a more specific example.

Comment: @TheBlueWizard, check the answer again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in this specific case where we could not change nothing of any classes or functions in the program, this does not respect. It would work for sure and it is a great way in any cases where you are free to code. I appreciate.